# Linear Congruential Generator C

Tags: c

- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 x86 (Debian Wheezy)
- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

I am writing a linear congruential generator. I have read that the higher order bits generated by a linear congruential generator have a higher period. I would like to use the higher order bits but I do not know how to. The current implementation I have uses values for 'a' and 'c' from the book Numerical Recipes because the greatest possible value of the equation ax+c can be expressed as a 64 bit integer.

```
#define ran32(seed) (uint32_t)((seed) * UINT64_C(1664525) + UINT64_C(1013904223))
```

I have tried the following in order to eliminate the lower order bits but from what I can tell it does not return values across the entire range of a unsigned 32 bit integer.

```
#define ran32(seed) (uint32_t)(((seed) * UINT64_C(1664525) + UINT64_C(1013904223)) / UINT64_C(256))
```

The idea is that integral division by 2^8(256) is equivalent to 'foo' >> 8. This idea was inspired by the following code segment I found in [rand()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html)'s documentation.

```
static unsigned long next = 1;
int myrand(void)  /* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767. */
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}

void mysrand(unsigned seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

Comment: The first thing that pops in my mind is ...why in the world would you do that?

Comment: This is a question and answer site not a code review site.

Comment: @BrandonYates I have updated my post so now it is a question.

Comment: @Blindy To answer your question I am interested in linear congruential generators. Now if you could answer my question I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be that the calculation:

```
seed * 1664525 + 1013904223
```

produces a 32-bit value (`uint32_t`), which is then assigned to a 64-bit variable.  You probably wanted to do that as a 64-bit calculation.

However, unless you are routinely overflowing the 64-bit numbers, your most significant bytes are not necessarily going to be very random.

I think your code is vulnerable to problems with endianness, too.

Your analysis that the minimum value of the expression is large ignores the modulus 2<sup>32</sup> arithmetic that is entailed by `uint32_t`.

Comment: The LCG is actually _(1664525 * Xₙ₋₁ + 1013904223) mod 2³²_, from _Numerical Recipes_

Comment: @ninjalj: OK - that suggests it should be a decent LCG PRNG.  However, I doubt that Numerical Recipes has the code messing with 64-bit values.

Comment: _Numerical Recipes_ has `j = 1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));`, which has its share of problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have changed my question if you could answer my new question it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at it.  If you hack at a PRNG, you will almost invariably get a less PR generator than if you leave it alone.  Read Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2 Seminumerical Algorithms" for some more information -- more information than I've got time to regurgitate (assuming I've ingested the information in the first place, which is debatable). It seems to me that you need a 40-bit PRNG and you will then drop the least significant 8 bits from the 32-bit result. But finding a 40-bit PRNG may be hard; a 64-bit one may be easier to find and may work just as well for you.

Comment: Incidentally, when searching on Google with 'Knuth PRNG' (mainly for the correct TAOCP reference), I came across [PRNG User Manual](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/prng/doc/prng.html), and that includes a table of constants for different sizes of modulus, including entries close to most values of 2^N (for N = 40 specifically, and all other values of N between 8 and 64).